# Google Advertising ID Opt Out Mechanism

Tags: android, admob, ads

On Android devices, there is, as I'm sure you're aware, an option for the user to opt-out of interest based ads, which can be access from Google Settings.

I just saw on the [Google Play Developer Programme Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) this quote:

> Usage. The Android advertising identifier must only be used for advertising and user analytics. The status of the “Opt-out of Interest-based Advertising” setting must be verified on each access of the ID.

It goes on to say

> Respecting users' selections. Upon reset, a new advertising identifier must not be connected to a previous advertising identifier or data derived from a previous advertising identifier without the explicit consent of the user. Furthermore, **you must abide by a user’s “Opt out of Interest-based Advertising” setting. If a user has enabled this setting, you may not use the advertising identifier for creating user profiles for advertising purposes or for targeting users with interest-based advertising**. Allowed activities include contextual advertising, frequency capping, conversion tracking, reporting and security and fraud detection.

All I want to do is display ads using AdMob and other Advertising networks.  The above terms *seem* to indicate that it's my responsibility to manually check this opt-out setting from my code and then disable interest based ads based if it's enabled.

Do I really need to *actively* check this myself? If I do need to can anyone give any examples of how I do this (and how I set my ad network up to not use interest-based ads) as I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

I would have though the Ad Netorks SDK's do all of this for us developers?  Or maybe these terms are directed at the Ad Networks themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ad networks should do this.
AdMob definitely does.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check it yourself you first need to get a `AdvertisingIdClient.Info` object by calling `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo()`, (not in the main thread).
Once you have the Info object you can call `info.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()` to check the user's preferences.